# Charts.js DataIndex not updating based on selected datasets

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/jfft219g/
You can see here I have 3 `datasets` i.e Hospital, Referral, Total. I am displaying the the `dataindexes` on top of each bar.
But now when I disable one `dataset` the `dataIndexes` are still there for the disabled `dataset`. How to manage this. Please check the fiddle for the running codes.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
<div id="patientsBarGraphDiv" style="border: 1px solid black">
                                    <canvas id="patientsBarGraph"></canvas> 
                                </div>  
var paitentData = {
      labels: ["Today", "Week", "Month", "Year"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "Hospital Patients",
        fillColor: "#79D1CF",
            strokeColor: "#79D1CF",

        data:[ 24, 20, 30, 40] // adding data for the hospital section
      }, {
        label: "Referral Patients",
       fillColor: "#79D1CF",
            strokeColor: "#79D1CF",

       data:[ 14, 24, 34, 44] // adding data for referral section
      },
      {
            label: "Total Patients",
            fillColor: "#79D1CF",
            strokeColor: "#79D1CF",

          data:[ 22, 32, 43, 52] // adding data for Total section
          } ]
    };
   var opt = {
             responsive: true,
                legend: {
                    position: 'top',
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Patients Graph'
                },
                hover: {
                    animationDuration: 1
                },

                animation: {
                    duration: 1,
                    onComplete: function () {
                        var chartInstance = this.chart,
                            ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
                        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)";
                        ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

                        this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                            var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                            meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                                var data = dataset.data[index];
                                ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);

                            });
                        });
                    }
                }
        };

     var ctx = document.getElementById("patientsBarGraph").getContext("2d");// getting the id of canvas
    var MyNewChart = new Chart(ctx,{
        type: 'bar',
        data: paitentData,
        options:opt
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following lines of code inside your `forEach` loop, that will take care of the  `dataIndex` updating issue :

```
var isDatasetVisible = chartInstance.controller.isDatasetVisible(i);
if (!isDatasetVisible) return;
```

Here is the [**working example on JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kubj4t53/)

Comment: and what if I want certain datasets to be inactive by default.

Comment: you can set `hidden: true` for your dataset, check the updated answer (example)